# Is there any risk in SELECT ... FOR UPDATE outside transaction scope in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, locking

In a project where I work the sql for selecting objects does always select for update, whether the context is a transaction or not.

My question is if it has any risk, or performance issue, or chance causing deadlock or something else naughty ?

I know that select for update can lock a row only inside a transaction and that is the common use case.

I provide below two concrete use cases, and after the select for update used regardless of inside of transaction or not.

## Use case 1 - Just select a book and return it

```
book = booksRepository->getBook(7);
return book;
```

## Use case 2 - Transaction, Select the book, check that is valid and if so update

```
bookRepository->startTransaction();
book = booksRepository->getBook(7);
if (//some condition with the book properties) {
   bookRepository->updateBookAuthor(7, 'bbb');
}
bookRepository->commitTransaction();
```

In both of the above examples, the function getBook inside the repository does select for update

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS
WHERE id = :id
FOR UPDATE;
```

I asked the other devs and the answer to why they do this was "Because otherwise we would have to create two functions in the repository, one getBook and one getBookForUpdate, so we just select always for update"...

That answer does not provide any insight or explanation for where I can learn, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 8):

A query is always in a transaction even if you don't start it explicitly.
`SELECT FOR UPDATE` acquires an exclusive lock on rows it matches. There is a possibility that other transactions want to modify same records and will have to wait until the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` finishes and release the lock.

So, nothing bad will happen if you run `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, but overall performance may be lower due to possible lock waits.

Deadlocks are possible, too. If another transaction holds a shared lock and then wants to update the records while `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is waiting.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. So basically this approach is wrong because can cause unecessary deadlocks, and a better solution would be to have two separate functions, one getBook and another one getBookForUpdate and use as required ? Or do you suggest another solution

Comment: If we have to label I'd say it's an "overkill", not "wrong". Your suggestion to have `getBook() ` and `getBookForUpdate()` makes sense. Or you can add a function argument `update=True/False` in `getBook()`.

Answer (score 1):

Every statement is in some transaction.  There are 3 cases:

- `autocommit=ON`, no preceding `BEGIN`:

The statement is a transaction, effectively `BEGIN; Sql; COMMIT;`

- `autocommit=OFF`, no preceding `BEGIN`:

All statements are part of the same transaction until you issue `COMMIT` (or some DDL that implicitly commits).  I dislike this case because it is too easy to forget to issue the `COMMIT`.

- `BEGIN` has occurred without a `COMMIT` yet:

All statements are part of the same transaction until you issue `COMMIT` (or some DDL that implicitly commits).

So...

If you write your code so that `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` (explicit or implicit) is as short a time as practical, then don't worry.

If you write long-running transactions, then this `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is just one of many cases where your code will stall unexpectedly.

That is, it is more important to watch the "big picture" than to focus on one detail.

Meanwhile, I believe (without proof) that your lone `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` could stall if some other connection is about to `UPDATE` the record.  But maybe that is a good thing?  When it does finish, it will have the updated values.